# How to sort and match data with multiple $http when Consume Restful APIs with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, rest

So following my last question of how to consume multiple $http, I need also to sort the data and match them. It's mean, I have the Albums, Photos and users:

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

For each Album I need to display the owner name and number of photos. 
So I try this to get the Album by Id, but it gives me error:

```
$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/'+ $scope.id + '/photos')
```

Or I also try this:

```
$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/'+ albumUsers.id + '/photos')
```

But still get error.

The question is if there's a way to link / create dependency between them, so the second controller basically rely on the first one? 
Thanks

Comment: show the full code

Answer (score 0):

So this is the controller to get the albums and the users

```
MyAlbum.controller('albumList', function($scope, $http, $q) {
$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums').
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.albumDetails = response.data;
    });

$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.albumUsers = response.data;
   });

$q.all(['http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums','http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',]).
    then(function(response){
        $scope.albumDetails = response[0].data;
        $scope.albumUsers= response[1].data;
});
```

});

And this the controller to get each album - for the example, I'm using a link to one specific album:

```
MyAlbum.controller('photoList', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos')
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.PhotoDetails = response.data;
});
```

});

The thing is that instead of albums/1 it should be albums/id

Answer (score 0):

You can chained the `$http` calls together.Success function of the first `$http` request calls the second `$http` request.

```
function firstCall() {   // It will return a promise.
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: firstAPIURL
    });
}

function dependantCall() {  // It will return a promise
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: secondAPIURL
    });
}

$scope.onloadRequest = function() {   // This function will execute on load the view/controller.
    firstCall()
     .then(function(result) {
        $scope.value = result.data; // Now that the server has answered, you can assign the value to $scope.value, and then, call the second function.

        dependantCall().then(function(dependentResult) {
            // Your code comes here
        }, function(dependentError){
             // If an error happened during the dependent call, handle it here.
        });

    }, function(error){ 
        // If an error happened during first call, handle it here.
    });
};

$scope.onloadRequest();
```